# vue-router 4: Matching optional, nested groups

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-router4

Is it possible to match (multiple) optional groups using `vue-router` v4, e.g. something like:

```
/places/(:county(/:municipality)?)?(/by/:order)?
```

This should preferabely match the following paths:

```
/places
/places/by/some-order
/places/some-county
/places/some-county/by/some-order
/places/some-county/some-muni
/places/some-county/some-muni/by/some-order
```

I have seen some similar questions, but none seem to work - at least not with vue-router 4 (which, if I understand correctly, no longer uses `path-to-regexp` internally?). Any options for achieving something like this if not possible, without writing a custom router?